# CodeIgniter pagination using query string with search

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am new in CodeIgniter. I am stuck some where in search with pagination. Somebody help me.

```
class Pagination2 extends My_controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->model('pagination_model');
        $userdata=$this->session->userdata('userdata');
        if(!isset($userdata['user_role']))
        {
            redirect(base_url('admin'));
        }
    }

    public function manage($page = 0)
    {

       $this->load->library('pagination');
       $per_page = 10;   
       $_POST = $_GET;
       $search= $this->input->get('book_name')?$this->input->get('book_name'):'NIL';
       $this->db->limit($per_page,$page);
       if($search=='NIL')
       {
        $data['content_fb'] = $this->db->get('tbl_books')->result();
       }
       else
       {
        $this->db->like('name', $search);
        $res = $this->db->get('tbl_books');
        $data['content_fb'] =  $res->result();
       }
       // $data['content_fb'] = $this->db->select('id')->limit($per_page,$page)->get('content_fb')->result();

        $config['base_url'] = base_url('pagintion2/manage');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tbl_books');
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '«';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '»';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        // CodeIgniter Pagination URL with GET Parameters
        // http://subhra.me/codeigniter-pagination-url-get-parameters/
        if (count($_GET) > 0) $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
        $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();   
        // echo $data['pagination_links'];   
        $data['templatepart']='backend/pagination2';
        $userdata= $this->session->userdata('userdata');
        $data['data']= $this->Admin_model->getdata('user',array('id'=>$userdata['id']));
        $this->load->view('backend/layout',$data);
   }
}
```

**Problem:**

When i generate query string eg. ?per_page=2 its given me a fatal error, and can't be able to manipulate query string.

eg:

```
localhost/xxx/pagintion2/manage?per_page=2&book_name=Learning
```

Error:

```
404 Page Not Found
```

Please give me some solution. If you have code regrading it please share with me.

Regards

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: manipulation of query-strings.

Comment: Please, paste __exact text__ of an error.

Comment: if($this->input->get('book_name')){
         $this->db->like('name', $search);
     }
     $this->db->limit($per_page,$page);
     $res = $this->db->get('tbl_books');
     $data['content_fb'] =  $res->result();

Answer (score 1):

1.Create SQL table for saving queries

```
        --
        -- Table structure for table `ci_query`
        --

        CREATE TABLE `ci_query` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `query_string` text,
          `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2. in folder "application/core" cerate file: My_input.php

   ```
   if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct access allowed.');


   /**
    * Description of My_input
    *
    * @author Dragan
    */
   class MY_Input extends CI_Input{

       function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
       }

       /**
       * Save query in database
       */
       function save_query($query_array){
           $CI =& get_instance();
           $CI->db->insert('ci_query', array('query_string' => http_build_query($query_array)));

           return $CI->db->insert_id();    
       }

       /**
       * Load query from database
       */
       function load_query($query_id) {

           $CI =& get_instance();

           $rows = $CI->db->get_where('ci_query', array('id' => $query_id))->result();
           if (isset($rows[0])) {
               parse_str($rows[0]->query_string, $_GET);       
           }

       }


       }
   ```
3. In your Controller cerate function

   ```
       public function search() {

                   $query_array = array(
                       'book_name' => $this->input->post('book_name')
                   );

                   $query_id = $this->input->save_query($query_array);
                   redirect("pagintion2/manage/$query_id");

               }
   ```
4. Change your manage function

   ```
    public function manage ($query_id = 0,$start=0){

               $this->input->load_query($query_id);  

               $query_array = array(
                   'book_name' => $this->input->get('book_name')
               );

               $per_page = 10;

               $search= $this->input->get('book_name')?$this->input->get('book_name'):'NIL';
                if($search=='NIL')
              {
               $data['content_fb'] = $this->db->get('tbl_books')->result();
              }
              else
              {
               $this->db->like('name', $search);
               $res = $this->db->get('tbl_books');
               $data['content_fb'] =  $res->result();
              }


               $this->load->library('pagination');
               $config['base_url'] = site_url()."pagintion2/manage/$query_id";
               $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tbl_books');
               $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
               $config['per_page'] = 10;
               $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
               $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
               $config['first_link'] = false;
               $config['last_link'] = false;
               $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
               $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
               $config['prev_link'] = '«';
               $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
               $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
               $config['next_link'] = '»';
               $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
               $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
               $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
               $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
               $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
               $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
               $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
               $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
               $this->pagination->initialize($config);

               $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

              // output search data
              $data['list_of_books_by_category'] =  $this->model_your_model_name->get_list_of_books_by_category($query_array, $per_page, $start);

               $data['templatepart']='backend/pagination2';
               $userdata= $this->session->userdata('userdata');
               $data['data']= $this->Admin_model->getdata('user',array('id'=>$userdata['id']));
               $this->load->view('backend/layout',$data);

           }
   ```